# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: meteor, referenceerror

Since yesterday I have been getting this error in the javascript console when I run meteor on a few of my projects. I also get the same errors when I run meteor's examples.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

It seems like it might be an error with underscore. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am running the latest version of meteor (0.6.4.1).

Comment: Are you using _ in a file in lib/ folder, or in a file that is loaded before underscore is?

Comment: No, I have never used Underscore on any of my projects. All of the errors in the console point to files within the meteor package. I've tried creating new meteor projects multiple times and I get the same result. At this point it seems that I need to try to re-install meteor.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding underscore in manually

```
meteor add underscore
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens to me on Ubuntu, where everything is going well, then all of a sudden I get this in Chrome, usually not FF.

Try starting with

> meteor --production

Survey all your browsers for this.  Often, it will resume working well later.  I think this suggests a problem with the ordering of the files when individually sent through the dev mode.  I've sometimes found errors through a different browser's console; each one seem to speak JS differently.